# How to retroactively remove certain types of files from several git commits

Tags: git, version-control, git-filter-branch

I have a small personal project that is a git repository with just a master branch and several commits in it. (19, actually.) I discovered that I accidentally included several .psd files in the repo. That happened on the 7th commit. I realized my error on the 17th commit and added .psd to .gitignore.

How do I retroactively remove certain files (in this case *.psd) from these commits? Alternatively, how do I remove their folder from the commits?

Would it be: `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.psd' HEAD`, as per [this page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)?

Answer (score 0):

Your command almost looks correct, except that you need to specify a *range* of commits over which to apply the filter branch.  I fear that as you have written it now, you might be applying it to your entire history, which might not be what you want.  Assuming you wanted to cover the range from the commit containing the `.psd` files to the present, you would use:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *.psd' HEAD~12..HEAD
```

I assume that you have 19 commits, in which `HEAD~12` would refer to the 7th commit.

**Update:**

If you are worried about breaking something while using `filter-branch`, then first push the branch to the remote as a backup:

```
git push origin your_branch
```

Better yet, push to a branch with a different name, e.g.

```
git push origin your_branch:backup_branch
```

If something were to go wrong, you could just delete your local branch and pull again from the remote.

Comment: I haven't run the command yet, luckily. Is there a way to run this command in a kind of test-run? Also, I would be fine with removing the .psd files from all the commits, but they're only present in several of them.

Comment: @Flobin I updated my answer, giving you a safety option you can use to protect against calamities.